# How to get billboard hot 100 data in a CSV format?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python and attempting to use Python 3 to scrape billboard data. I am using the python billboard api (billboard.py) and want to get the hot 100 tracks in a csv format with Billboard Number, Artist Name, Song Title, Last Week Number, Peak Position and Weeks as headers. I have been looking at this for hours with no luck so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import requests, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100'

with open('Billboard_Hot100.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['Billboard Number','Artist Name','Song Title','Last Week Number','peak_position','weeks_on_chart'])

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

for container in soup.find_all("article",class_="chart-row"):

    billboard_number = container.find(class_="chart-row__current-week").text

    artist_name_a_tag = container.find(class_="chart-row__artist").text.strip()

    song_title = container.find(class_="chart-row__song").text

    last_week_number_tag = container.find(class_="chart-row__value")
    last_week_number = last_week_number_tag.text

    peak_position_tag = last_week_number_tag.find_parent().find_next_sibling().find(class_="chart-row__value")
    peak_position = peak_position_tag.text

    weeks_on_chart_tag = peak_position_tag.find_parent().find_next_sibling().find(class_="chart-row__value").text

    print(billboard_number,artist_name_a_tag,song_title,last_week_number,peak_position,weeks_on_chart_tag)
    writer.writerow([billboard_number,artist_name_a_tag,song_title,last_week_number,peak_position,weeks_on_chart_tag])
```

The csv file returned has the headers but the columns contain no information. Am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like you have the classes wrong. Try inspecting the page again. For example, the class `chart-row` should actually be `chart-list-item`.

Comment: @JoePatten Thanks for your quick response. Is there an easy way to get the correct classes? Apologies, I am completely new to this but willing to learn!

Comment: Solved - thank you

Answer (score 0):

Can you work with this?

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get('https://www.billboard.com/charts/hot-100')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
line = tree.xpath('//span[@class="chart-list-item__title-text"]/text()')
line = line.replace('\n','')
```

Here's a link that I bookmarked a long time ago.  It has helped me a lot over the course of time.

https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/scrape/